# How Can I Echo A Managed Attribute With An Object In Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

I am Again here with my learning problem in magento. I created a field in for my products Catalog/Attributes/Manage Attributes. Now I want to display this Field with the product Information. When I use This Code

```
$_product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
$_product->load($product->getId());
echo "<pre>"; print_r($_product->getDelivery());exit;
```

I am able to print other values like name by writing this :

```
 echo "<pre>"; print_r($_product->getName());exit;
```

Can anyone tell me how can I print those attributes that i have added manually through Admin interface..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try and see what's inside

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($_product->getData());exit;
```

Comment: and how can i print any value e.g I am having a field "surname" There and i am able to see it as a part of printed array. how can i separately print it. well I am new to php

Comment: every value you see there can be asked separately

Comment: Yes I understand that But when I try to separate one I am getting an error.. please Do me this favor. I have asked another Question regarding that here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121845/print-nth-value-by-array-key-in-php Please Help